# What's the process to use a cellular wifi hotspot as an ISP?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, routing

I'm currently waiting out an ISP outage. I have a Radware box that has static rules to push clients to the secondary ISP should the primary ISP go down. My secondary is the one that's down, so nothing is really impacted. Some servers are statically assigned to the secondary so they don't have to compete for bandwidth.

- The Radware has 192.168.100.1.
- The primary ISP's firewall's internal interface has 192.168.100.2. It's the default route on the Radware.
- The secondary ISP's firewall's internal interface has 192.168.100.3.

Could I install Ubuntu on a laptop (or desktop with wireless) with the wired NIC connected to the Radware and the wireless adapter connected to the Verizon hotspot and forward traffic from the cellular internet side to the LAN? If so, which packages would I need?

I have OpenVPN on a different server and I don't have routing packages installed; rather, I have forwarding rules in `iptables` that translate the traffic. Is that all that's needed? I imagine then I would only need to use `iptables` to block incoming connections, and optionally allow specific outbound connections if I wasn't using "ACCEPT" as the default policy for outbound conns.

Regardless of the process, I wouldn't need to serve anything over the cell backup, so address translation isn't needed.

My domain controllers already manage internal DNS and DHCP, so that's not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Routers at your Internet edge supporting multi homed. With multiple WAN ports (Ethernet, USB, or integrated 4G modem) and failover capability. Possibly you could use your existing box if you can add a third WAN interface.

Usually, cell data modems intended for this purpose have Ethernet or USB, and not only wifi like a hotspot. Those ports are more common on routers and firewalls, and perform better than wireless anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I was wanting to use a laptop or small desktop that I already had on hand at work. The residential routers we use as WAPs have a USB port where a cell modem can be connected, but there aren't a lot of compatible units and the PTB don't want to spend any money.

Comment: A router with 2 or 3 WAN ports plugged into modems is going to be easier. Less internet facing security concerns due to general purpose devices to patch. You could build your own pfSense boxes or similar, if you wanted to maintain that.